# How to apply different style sheets to VCL buttons in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

I have two VCL buttons in a Delphi application. But I want both buttons to have different VCL styles sheets.

How can I apply different Delphi VCL style sheets to the buttons?

Comment: I improved grammar and wording so that the question is easier to understand. I also improved the title so that it better reflects the content of the question. It would be great if you could add some code to the question. This makes it easier for users to answer the question.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2015/09/15/creating-a-custom-button-style-with-rad-studio-10-seattle/)? I don't know if it works with VCL styles.

Comment: I'm asking for VCL... It is not working....in VCL....

Answer (score 1):

The VCL Styles architecture doesn't allow use different styles on the controls. If you want use different styles on the buttons you must draw the control your self.